# Windows CMD/Power Shell sleep's when i do not interact

Tags: windows, powershell, cmd, prompt

I use the power shell a lot to run react-native aplications and Android emulators. But every time i have to open the shell and press enter to wakeup the shell, because aparrently it stops running or lose priority when i do not interact with it for some time.

So, there's some way to prevent the cmd from stop processing my tasks?

Comment: Don't forget to ask your question. (As an aside, I have never seen this behavior)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Other people have reported this as an issue but it turned out to be user error.  I can only assume that you have the same problem.

Chances are that quickedit mode is on and you have somehow clicked in the window thus freezing the process.

See  [this post on serverfault](https://serverfault.com/questions/204150/sometimes-powershell-stops-sending-output-until-i-press-enter-why)

And  [this post on MS technet](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/scriptcenter/en-US/baa222b8-2a4c-4a8c-9e12-52a2358c953a/why-does-powershell-quotpausequot-until-i-press-enter-or-the-down-arrow-key?forum=ITCG)

Comment: Very thanks! Looks like this was the problem. I followed  the instructions in the links, but will take some time to confirm if realy was this.